# Updating a sub key element in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following state object:

```
state = {
        header: {
            ActiveHeaderIndex: this.props.ActiveIndex,
            isHeaderAscending: true,
            groupByHeader: []
        }
    }
```

I want to update groubByHeader when a function is called like this:

```
const Clicked = (temporary) => {
    this.setState({
            state: {
                header:
                {
                    ...this.state.header,
                    groupByHeader: temporary
                }
            }
        });
}
```

though I am using this logic, yet my groupByHeader isn't updating. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any better way to update nested object in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a key `state` to the state object, where the actual keys to update are inside of it. Remove that `state` key and it should work:

```
const Clicked = (temporary) => {
    this.setState({
        header: {
            ...this.state.header,
            groupByHeader: temporary
        }
    });
}
```